# VSCode Intellisense not fully working with ES6 imports?

Tags: ecmascript-6, visual-studio-code, intellisense

I am having trouble getting Intellisense to work completely with ES6 imports.

Doing the following from `/index.js` gets Intellisense to work correctly:

[image: working example]

However, doing the following from `/index.js` breaks Intellisense:

[image: broken example]

The directory structure is:

```
| modules
|-- cars.js
|-- index.js
| index.js
| jsconfig.json
```

The contents of each file are:

**modules/cars.js**

```
export default {
  audi: 'R8',
  dodge: 'Durango',
};
```

**modules/index.js**

```
import cars from './cars';

export default {
  cars,
};
```

**jsconfig.json**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es6",
    "module": "commonjs"
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Cars isn't a named export of `modules/index.js`. The default export of `modules/index.js` is an object, which then contains `cars`. To get what you want, make the contents of `modules/index.js` this:

```
export { default as cars } from './cars';
```